# Xcodeの代わりにエディターを使う利点は？

Tags: swift, xcode, vscode, エディタ

Xcodeがひどく使いにくく、エディターでSwiftを書くというような記事をたまに見かけますが、エディター（例えばVS Code）だとそれほど開発は捗るものなのでしょうか？
エディターの利点はどのようなことなのでしょうか？
このサイトに適切な質問なのか、分からないのですが。

Comment: そもそもXcode自体もエディタなので、この質問はふたつのエディタの差異を聞いている質問に思えました。また、Xcodeが使いにくいということがaquaさんのご覧になった記事に書かれているなら、それこそが他のエディタを使う理由なので、どういった部分が使いにくいと書かれているのかを調べると答えが見つかるのかな、とも思いました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、IDEであるXcodeを「Xcode自体もエディタ」と言ってしまうと質問の意図からかけ離れたものになってしまうように思います。「多少使いにくい点があるままIDEを使う」か「(プラグインなどでIDE的な機能を付け足すにしても)エディターを使う」かの対比でしょう。「IDE vs エディターの対比」と、「エディター同士の比較」とは全然別物のように思われます。

Answer (score 3):

そもそも「ひどく使いにくい」と言うこと自体が個人の主観ですので、別のエディタに変えて捗るかどうかは人それぞれだと思います。
あとは単にXcodeに慣れておらず、例えばVS Codeを今まで開発に使ってきたので、キーボードコマンドなんかが体に染み付いているだけ、という話ではないでしょうか。

単にコードを書く、と言う点だけなら使い慣れたエディタの方がストレスなく作業できる場合もあるということです。逆にXcodeからプログラミングに入った人は急にVS Codeでプログラムを書けと言われても戸惑うだけだと思います。
ちなみに私は結構コード補完に頼ってしまうので、補完候補をリストアップするために動作がもっさりになっても、Xcodeを使うと思います。

また、プログラミングはコードを書いて終わり、ではないので、複雑なデバッグ作業なんかはやはりXcodeでないと難しいと思います。あくまでも道具ですので、何を使うか、というこだわりはあっていいと思いますが、他人の意見を無条件に信じる必要もないと思います。

今現在それほど手に馴染んだエディタがないのであれば、別に気にせずXcodeを使ってもいいんじゃないでしょうか。
ご自身がどうしてもXcodeのエディタが使いにくいと感じたら、別のエディタを試してみるのもいいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！僕はXcodeのストーリーボードが無くてはならない機能だと思っております。なので別のエディターのみでの開発で、それを上回ることが可能なのか疑問で、この質問をさせていただきました。別の議題になってしまうかもしれませんが、コードを書く部分だけを好きなエディターに変える方法があるのかもしれませんね。